# using admin functions on frontend

Tags: plugin-development, functions, admin

I'm updating my plugin to rely on internal functions of WordPress. I'm about to use `wp_generate_attachment_metadata`, but this function seems to be only available in the admin section.

Is there an easy was to enable it on the frontend as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following line before using the function.

```
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
```